# Android studio IDE internal error occurred Error says Unable to serialize DslActivationStatus state

Tags: flutter, dart

1.Why  **Unable to serialize DslActivationStatus state** happens
2. How to solve this error 
3.I have provided screenshot of this error

[Please look at  the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekcgp.png)

```
Unable to serialize DslActivationStatus state

com.intellij.util.xmlb.XmlSerializationException: Can't serialize instance of class org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.dsl.DslActivationStatus$State
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.XmlSerializer.serialize(xmlSerializer.kt:63)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.XmlSerializer.serialize$default(xmlSerializer.kt:47)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.SaveSessionBaseKt.serializeState(SaveSessionBase.kt:46)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.SaveSessionBase.setState(SaveSessionBase.kt:20)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.commitComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:283)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.commitComponents$intellij_platform_configurationStore_impl(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:199)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.commitComponents$intellij_platform_configurationStore_impl(ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.kt:89)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.doCreateSaveSessionManagerAndCommitComponents$intellij_platform_configurationStore_impl(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:155)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl$createSaveSessionManagerAndSaveComponents$3.invokeSuspend(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:146)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:236)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:435)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:403)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:757)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:706)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:375)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.jdom.IllegalDataException: The data "org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
categoryTransformgdsl: 1: unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 1, column 5.
   ����
```

Comment: please supply code.

Comment: i have supplied the code please check

Comment: would have been nice to remove all that clutter like 14 of the 15 dispatch methods which dont add any benefit to explain the problem.

Comment: please re-add the code.

Comment: this error shows at the bottom right corner of android studio...This error shows even when I run flutter demo app [increment counter app]

Comment: I have added the error  code please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function list you are calling the functions on list creation. This makes flutter throws this exception (which is correct because Navigator tries to route during the build phase of the other widget).

Apart from that, the code is quite weird to me but to get it to work you need to use this list:

```
final List<Function> ontaps = [
    functionOne,
    functionTwo,
    functionThree,
    functionFour,
    functionFive,
    functionSix,
    functionSeven,
    functionEight,
    functionNine,
    functionTen,
    functionEleven,
    functionTwelve,
    functionThirteen,
    functionFourteen,
    functionFifteen
  ];
```

Comment: then mark this answer as correct so that this one is closed. And why did you removed the code? This way nobody can learn from the answer. You should really read the stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: stackoverflow sensored my ability to ask  questions. I can not ask new questions that is why I edit previously asked questions to ask a new question.. thank you...I will re-add code to this question after the removal of ban on me