# Unable to serialize DslActivationStatus state...Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

If this is a stupid question because I made some terrible mistake, please let me know. Anyways, I just encountered the error and after searching on internet for quite some time, the only similar error that I could find was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232903/android-studio-ide-internal-error-occurred-error-says-unable-to-serialize-dslact) But my situation was different.
1). I tried to create a new project from File menu of a previous project.
2). I clicked on Basic Activity and selected mininimum supported API to be 19.
3). I was following [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-available-resources/#2) tutorial by Google Developers.
4). I was previously able to successfully build and run from Empty Templates, but now, even they show this same error.

Here are two screenshots: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juw5p.png) & [Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYOqg.png)

I have tried to restart computer. I have NOT yet tried to download and re-install Android Studio yet. I do not know of any good troubleshooting besides restarting computer; so, if someone wants to share some tips, please be kind enough to do it.

I have not edited or tried to do anything in the automatically created project. I have not editted any file, until I noticed that even @color/primaryColor could not be resolved. So, I went on to look into the res/values/color file and found out that it had no color values in it, instead there was a single line:  androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-au. So, I checked further, and found out that many of the automatically generated files had several errors in them.

I am on a Windows 10 machine. Please help, if this question needs to be edited, please let me know. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If this question needs more screenshots or code or anything, please instead of downvoting, let me know.

Comment: Show me your app gradle setup?

Comment: After waiting 3 hours, I have uninstalled Android Studio. But, I have checked build files, all the gradle.build files were pretty normal.

Comment: If you using navigation component you should add it to dependencies